# Enable and Disable Pan in SVG Zoom API

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

```js
console.clear();

first_image()

function first_image(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<div id="main-container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border:1px solid #DA096C;"><svg id="svg-id_alt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: inline; width: inherit; min-width: inherit; max-width: inherit; height: inherit; min-height: inherit; max-height: inherit;" version="1.1"><path data-key="12345" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 224.34 585.57 L 224.34 586.6 L 225.22 588.68 L 226.1 589.71 L 227.87 590.75 L 231.39 590.75 L 233.15 589.71 L 234.04 588.68 L 234.92 586.6 L 234.92 584.53 L 234.04 582.46 L 232.27 579.35 L 223.46 568.98 L 235.8 568.98 "/></svg></div>';
first_image_scroll()

function first_image_scroll(){
$(function() {
  panZoomInstance = svgPanZoom('#svg-id_alt', {
    zoomEnabled: true,
    controlIconsEnabled: false,
    zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.7,
    minZoom: 0.005
  });
  //panZoomInstance.zoom(1.1);  
})
}
}

function enable_pan_func(){}

function disable_pan_func(){}
```

```css
.main-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg-pan-zoom@3.5.0/dist/svg-pan-zoom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <button onclick="enable_pan_func()">Enable Pan</button>
  <button onclick="disable_pan_func()">Disable Pan</button>
    
<div>
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Above is an SVG text which can be panned and zoomed. May I ask how to **disable and enable only the Pan Functionality** while still keeping the **Zoom function Enabled at all time**?
I have created this 2 button (Enable Pan and Disable Pan)

I will really appreciate any help I can get :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of beforePan function.

```js
console.clear();
let panZoomInstance;
let isPanEnabled = true;

first_image()

function first_image(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<div id="main-container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border:1px solid #DA096C;"><svg id="svg-id_alt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: inline; width: inherit; min-width: inherit; max-width: inherit; height: inherit; min-height: inherit; max-height: inherit;" version="1.1"><path data-key="12345" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 224.34 585.57 L 224.34 586.6 L 225.22 588.68 L 226.1 589.71 L 227.87 590.75 L 231.39 590.75 L 233.15 589.71 L 234.04 588.68 L 234.92 586.6 L 234.92 584.53 L 234.04 582.46 L 232.27 579.35 L 223.46 568.98 L 235.8 568.98 "/></svg></div>';
first_image_scroll()

function first_image_scroll(){
$(function() {
  panZoomInstance = svgPanZoom('#svg-id_alt', {
    zoomEnabled: true,
    controlIconsEnabled: false,
    zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.7,
    minZoom: 0.005,
    beforePan: (oldPan, newPan) => {
      if (!isPanEnabled) return false;
      return newPan;
    }
  });
  //panZoomInstance.zoom(1.1);  
})
}
}

function enable_pan_func(){
  isPanEnabled = true;
}

function disable_pan_func(){
  isPanEnabled = false;
}
```

```css
.main-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg-pan-zoom@3.5.0/dist/svg-pan-zoom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <button onclick="enable_pan_func()">Enable Pan</button>
  <button onclick="disable_pan_func()">Disable Pan</button>
    
<div>
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

By default the Pan is Enabled. If you want you can turn that off by passing panEnabled option in the initializer and then matched that with the variable declared in the top.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Hope you have a great day ahead !!! :)

Comment: Hi, when you double click on my svg path, you will see that it will get zoomed in when double click which is somehow a bit annoying to me. Do you know how to disable and enable it too by any chance :) ?

Comment: Add this option in the options list. dblClickZoomEnabled: false